# ListAdapter how to make long click listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app which uses ListAdapter as it's adapter, i manager to add a click listener to it like the following:

```
class LettureListAdapter(private val mListener: (Testata) -> Unit) : ListAdapter<Testata, LettureListAdapter.LettureViewHolder>(LettureComparator()) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LettureViewHolder {
        return LettureViewHolder.create(parent)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LettureViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            current.let { testata ->
                mListener.invoke(testata)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the Fragment i call it like the following:

```
adapter = LettureListAdapter {
    model.setIdTestata(it.id.toLong())
    activateTabs()
}
```

But how can i make an adapter like that for a long click?

i would manage both long click and normal click on recyclerVIew item..

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding another listener like this:

```
class LettureListAdapter(private val clickListener: (Testata) -> Unit, private val longListener: (Testata) -> Unit)
```

And added the long click listener in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LettureViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(current)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        current.let { testata ->
            clickListener.invoke(testata)
        }
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
        current.let { testata ->
            longListener.invoke(testata)
            true
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my activity it looks like this:

```
adapter = LettureListAdapter({
    corpoViewModel.setIdTestata(it.id.toLong())
    activateTabs()
}, {
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "LONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setOnLongClickListener() for long click. And you can also use setOnClickListener() as well for normal click. So both clicks work with different functionality.

**In JAVA**

```
   holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //you code here
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**In KOTLIN**

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
   // your code here
     return@setOnLongClickListener true
}
```